# Does Google Sheet onEdit trigger is being executed after sheet is recalculated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a Spreadsheet with onEdit trigger.
A1 is used by other cells, say B1.

The trigger "listen" to A1 modification, and than 
gets **B1 new value** to perform its job.

Question is it guarantees that **B1** has been already recalculated when `onEdit` is fired?
for example:

Cell **B1** contains the formula `=A1+1`

Now 1 is typed into **A1**

```
function onEdit(e){

  var changeRng  = e.range;

  if (changeRng.getA1Notation() == "A1") {
    //Read value from B2
    var b1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 2).getValue();
  }

}
```

Is variable `b1` guarantee to be 2?

Comment: @ross. I wasn't clear. `onEdit` is triggered by **A1** edit. Question Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `onEdit()` is triggered by an edit of `A1` there is no garantee that `B1` has finished recalculating before `onEdit()` is fired, especially if the recalculation of `B1` is time intensive.

I recommend you to incorporate at the beginning of you `onEdit` function a [`Utilities.sleep()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer)) call to give the value in `B1` enough time to recalculate.